# Octopus script module wrongly goes into IF

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a script module in `Octopus Deploy`, which would create a new web application in IIS. As part of that it also creates an IIS pool, if one doesn't exists already.

```
function Create-WebApplication($webSite, $alias, $physicalPath, $poolName)
{
    $pool = "IIS:\AppPools\$poolName"
    if (Test-Path $pool)
    {
        Write-Host "IIS pool already exists: $poolName"
    }
    else
    {
        #--Always gets into this else condition, no matter exists or not--
        Write-Host "Creating IIS pool: $poolName"
        New-WebAppPool -Name $poolName
        Set-ItemProperty $pool -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value "v4.0" 
    }
    Write-Host "Creating website: $webSite\$alias"
    New-WebApplication -Name $alias -Site $webSite -PhysicalPath $physicalPath -ApplicationPool $poolName -Force

    Write-Host "Setting the application pool: $poolName"
    Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$webSite\$alias -name applicationPool -value $poolName -Force
}
```

The problem is, it always does get into the `else` condition, where it tries to create the app pool.
Same script working fine in PowerShell ISE.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Who defines the `IIS:` drive? It sounds like it's there only in the ISE (where consecutive runs of a script execute in the _same_ session, with potential side effects from previous runs). Note that `Test-Path` will _not_ complain about a non-existent drive; e.g., `Test-Path NoSuchDrive:AndNoSuchPathEither` simply returns `$False`

Comment: A first guess would be Octopus may not support the IIS provider or the module/snapin is not loading properly to create that PSDrive.

Comment: IIS snap-in loaded? This is a shot in the dark. I don't have the IIS snap-in loaded. If I call Test-Path with the parameters from your example I get False too. If whatever service account is running this code doesn't have the snap-in loaded, it will also get false.

Comment: OK, it was just the snapin. After adding the `Import-Module WebAdministration` as a 1st line inside the function all is working fine.

Comment: I think it would be fair to accept the answer from one of the 1st commentators pointing to a need for snap-in. Will one submit?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to import the **WebAdministration** module to work against the IIS drive, otherwise `Test-Path` will always fail when checking against it.